# Get the alphabetical sorted data with wpdb

Tags: functions, wpdb

I have a function in my WP which get the data from database,

Here is the function

```
function thebook_get_provider_types() {
    global $wpdb;
    static $provider_types;

    if (! isset($provider_types)) {
        $row = $wpdb->get_row(sprintf('SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_id = %d', CF_PROVIDER_TYPES));
        $provider_types = unserialize($row->meta_value);
    }

    return $provider_types;
}
```

Is there any way to get the data by alphabetical sort?
I wasn't able to find the related documentation in CODEX, Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An simple `ORDER BY` clause will order alphabetically. How is this WordPress related?

Comment: @s_ha_dum http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb
It's not?

Comment: `$wpdb` is a thin wrapper for running `SQL`. Everything of significance in your code is `SQL`. You can run that code as easily without `$wpdb` as with it, and the answer is pure `SQL` syntax. Even in the context of WordPress, pure `SQL` is likely to be off-topic.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Thanks man, i didn't know that, thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

It isn't really WordPress-related indeed, but then again, OP doesn't seem to know that, so here's your answer :-). However, next time: this isn't WordPress-related, please post PHP-questions in the corresponding SE.

Sorting a PHP array can be achieved by using the [`sort`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.sort.php) function, which sorts an array alphabetically by its values.

I'm assuming you have a one-dimensional array. If not, you should really edit your question with more information.

```
function thebook_get_provider_types() {
    global $wpdb;
    static $provider_types;

    if (! isset($provider_types)) {
        $row = $wpdb->get_row(sprintf('SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_id = %d', CF_PROVIDER_TYPES));
        $provider_types = unserialize($row->meta_value);
    }

    // Sort the array alphabetically
    sort( $provider_types );

    return $provider_types;
}
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the info, i didn't know that. Also it still doesn't sort my data, could you help me with that?

Comment: I've edited my answer, this should work (assuming that your array is one-dimensional).

Comment: Really appreciate it, actually somebody wrote this function, it's over my head to give you more info, but your code doesn't work. I'll update here once i get more info.